Laravel retrieve latest of many morphed results
I need help with my laravel 11 project. I have a table which acts as a morph table which would work with morphedByMany. But for this particular model I only need to retrieve one entry. My tables are: Site, Domain and then the intermidiate table: Siteable. Siteable defines the site_id, siteable_type and siteable_id columns. The following relationship defined at the Site model would retrieve all of my domains for the site, but a site should only have one domain:
public function domains(): MorphToMany
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(Domain::class, 'siteable');
}

I tried to change this to:
public function domain(): HasOneThrough
{
    return $this->hasOneThrough(Domain::class, Siteable::class, 'siteable_id', 'id', 'id');
}

Basically, a Site can have one domain, and as many of other models as it chooses, thus the following schema:
Schema::create('siteables', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->ulid('id')->primary()->index();
    $table->foreignUlid('site_id')->index()->constrained()->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->ulidMorphs('siteable');
    $table->timestamps();

    // define indexes for performance
    $table->index(['site_id', 'siteable_type', 'siteable_id']);
});

What am i missing to retrieve one record?
UPDATE
SQL error I get after attempting morphOne:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'domains.siteable_id' in 'field list' (Connection: mysql, SQL: select `domains`.* from `domains` inner join (select MAX(`domains`.`id`) as `id_aggregate`, `domains`.`siteable_id`, `domains`.`siteable_type` from `domains` where `domains`.`siteable_id` in (01hy0zwf63wpt6t8c64q1388q9, 01hy0zxw8yb1nncrw7ytg50wwr) and `domains`.`siteable_type` = App\Models\Site group by `domains`.`siteable_id`, `domains`.`siteable_type`) as `latestOfMany` on `latestOfMany`.`id_aggregate` = `domains`.`id` and `latestOfMany`.`siteable_type` = `domains`.`siteable_type` and `latestOfMany`.`siteable_id` = `domains`.`siteable_id`).

UPDATE 2 (with created_at)
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'domains.siteable_id' in 'field list' (Connection: mysql, SQL: select `domains`.* from `domains` inner join (select MAX(`domains`.`id`) as `id_aggregate`, min(`domains`.`created_at`) as `created_at_aggregate`, `domains`.`siteable_id`, `domains`.`siteable_type` from `domains` inner join (select MAX(`domains`.`created_at`) as `created_at_aggregate`, `domains`.`siteable_id`, `domains`.`siteable_type` from `domains` where `domains`.`siteable_id` in (01hy0zwf63wpt6t8c64q1388q9, 01hy0zxw8yb1nncrw7ytg50wwr) and `domains`.`siteable_type` = App\Models\Site group by `domains`.`siteable_id`, `domains`.`siteable_type`) as `latestOfMany` on `latestOfMany`.`created_at_aggregate` = `domains`.`created_at` and `latestOfMany`.`siteable_type` = `domains`.`siteable_type` and `latestOfMany`.`siteable_id` = `domains`.`siteable_id` group by `domains`.`siteable_id`, `domains`.`siteable_type`) as `latestOfMany` on `latestOfMany`.`id_aggregate` = `domains`.`id` and `latestOfMany`.`created_at_aggregate` = `domains`.`created_at` and `latestOfMany`.`siteable_type` = `domains`.`siteable_type` and `latestOfMany`.`siteable_id` = `domains`.`siteable_id`).


You could utilise a query scope for this that simply gets the latest domain id as a global select then eager loads the Domain using that id.
public function latestDomain(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Domain::class, 'latest_domain_id', 'id');
}

public function scopeWithLatestDomain($query): void
{
    $query->addSelect(['latest_domain_id' => Domain::select('id')])
        ->whereColumn('siteables.id', 'domains.siteable_id')
        ->where('domains.siteable_type', static::class)
        ->latest()
        ->take(1)
        ->with(['latestDomain']);
}

This is untested and simply just a PoC but from what I can guage from your OP, it should be enough on its own. Usage:
Siteable::withLatestDomain()


Ideally looking to do it with a relationship. Additionally, where would the latestDomain relation go? I have my Site model with my Siteable model and Domain model.

After much trial and error. What worked, was to create a domain relationship in the Site model as such:
/**
    * Get the domain for the site
    */
public function domain(): HasOneThrough
{
    return $this->hasOneThrough(
        Domain::class,
        Siteable::class,
        'site_id',
        'id',
        'id',
        'siteable_id'
    )->where('siteable_type', Domain::class)->orderByDesc('created_at');
}

